# Vuetify: v-model looks deprecated

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify 1.0.14 to create my application.
While I load a page though, I received this error message:

```
vuetify.js?dc48:19429 [Vuetify] v-model has been deprecated

found in

---> <VExpansionPanelContent>
```

Those are the lines of code this warning message refers to:

```
            <v-expansion-panel>
                <v-expansion-panel-content key="annotations" :value="sideFocusItem.default === 'annotations'">
                    <div slot="header">Annotations:</div>
                    <annotations v-if="loadAnnotationBuilder"></annotations>
                </v-expansion-panel-content>
            </v-expansion-panel>
```

I have some trouble figuring out where `v-model` is used and how it's possible that it has been deprecated. It's only a warning but how can I fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a confusing warning, as Vue itself has not deprecated `v-model`. Looking at the [Vuetify source](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/a99b6a0531711d913395418df3a28b348599e63d/src/components/VExpansionPanel/VExpansionPanelContent.ts#L77), it looks like `v-expansion-panel-content` throws this warning when you pass it a `value` prop.

The [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/expansion-panels) mentions you are supposed to use `v-model` and/or `expand` on the parent Expansion panel (instead of the panel *content*).

> Expansion panels can be controlled externally by modifying the v-model. Its value corresponds to a zero-based index of the currently opened expansion panel content. If expand prop is used then it is an array of booleans where the index corresponds to the index of the content.

Here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0BI9I9oAYYk) that seems to solve the same problem you're running into.

Comment: However, there is a `value` property in `v-expansion-panel-content` API. It says that it `Controls the opened/closed state of content`. Did that change with recent versions? Perhaps docs wasn't updated? Note I haven't tested this yet.

Comment: @Traxo I don't follow Vuetify closely. But it looks like they aren't updating the docs until it's _fully_ removed. It would be nice if they at least mentioned the planned deprecation there.